# "End"-align element in CSS

Tags: html, css, webkit, right-to-left

I have a project which needs to correctly handle both left-to-right and right-to-left text. In the design, some of the elements are right-aligned. This means that for rtl, they need to be left-aligned.

Is there a way to align things to the "end" instead of to the "right" using CSS? I am specifically targeting Webkit here.

Examples of what I'd like to do:

```
float: end; /* instead of float: right */
```

or

```
position: absolute;
end: 0px; /* instead of right: 0px */
```

Obviously neither one of these actually works.

I know it is possible to set a style for rtl, and use that to change all my `right: 0px;` to `left: 0px`. I'm looking for a better solution here.

---

**Edit:**

For some context, the page has elements all over the place doing all sorts of things. But the one I am specifically working on now is a menu-bar. It has some static buttons on the left, a variable breadcrumb in the middle, and some static buttons on the right. The breadcrumb is supposed to flow like text normally would (left-to-right or right-to-left as the case may be).

Comment: Can you provide more context here?  There *may* be a solution, but it depends greatly on the surrounding elements.

Comment: This should be possible to accomplish if you use very well thought-out, semantic markup and classes - that way you can change alignment related CSS on the fly on a per-page basis but still have the advantage of identical markup.  For example, have an `.alignend` class or something that floats left or right based on some more specific style override (e.g. if you dynamically added `rtl` and `ltr` classes to the `body` based on which kind of page it was).

Comment: you could potentially use flexbox's justify-content property, which accepts flex-start and flex-end as options.

Comment: flexbox may be the way to go.

Comment: Note that as of recently, you can use things like `float: inline-end` and `text-align:end` which do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox was designed with more than just your typical LTR way of writing in mind.  It features language like `flex-start` and `flex-end` in regards to alignment and justification.  The way you describe the elements in question, it may not be necessary to use them.

http://codepen.io/cimmanon/pen/bdynv (contains both LTR and RTL examples)

```
<nav class="rtl">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/50" alt="Cat Button" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/80/50" alt="Other Cat Button" />

  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
  </ul>

  <img src="http://placekitten.com/100/50" alt="Cat Button" />
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/80/50" alt="Other Cat Button" />
</nav>
```

The CSS:

```
nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  /* optional */
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -moz-box-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

ul {
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex: 1;
  flex: 1;
}
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.rtl {
  direction: rtl;
}
```

Note that the same thing could be achieved using the table/table-cell display properties, but it would require additional elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using a bit of JavaScript (here, with jQuery) we can check the text direction and adjust the float with a class name and some CSS.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/5P34N/3/)

**JS:**

```
$(".float-end").each(function(){
    if($(this).css("direction") === "rtl"){
      $(this).addClass("rtl");  
    }
})
```

**CSS:**

```
.float-end {
    float: right;
}
.float-end.rtl {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if this would answer your specific question:

Apply this CSS setting to the parent of your element:

```
position: relative;
```

Now, you can set the position of the child of the parent, this will prevent the element from moving out of your box. E.g.

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

would move the child to the bottom of the parent element, but not further.

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't tried `text-align:right` I would recommend starting there. The text must be in a block element such as a `p` or `div` tag, and the `width: XXXpx` will need to be set so that the left AND right edges are where you want them.

Comment: `text-align:right` is not as nice as `text-align:end` which works both for rtl and ltr.